# Partition PostgreSQL table based on FK attribute

Tags: postgresql, table-partitioning

I want to *parition* my huge table to solve a performance issue, but the attibute on which I want to parition my table resides in another table that is related by **FK**.

Here are my tables:

```
Article (Table1)
 id
 submit_date
 ...

Concept (Table2)
 id
 article_id (FK)
 ...
```

So, I want to parition **Concept** table based on **submit_date** attribute from the article table (like split it by months). Is it possible with **PostgreSQL**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can partition on whatever field(s) or complex queries you want - The `INSERT` is handled by a trigger, and the `SELECT` by table inheritance.

In your case the trigger for the **Concept** table would need to do an appropriate query on **submit_date** to determine which partition to insert into.  If you already have data in the **Concept** table you will need to do a little work to partition the existing data:

1. ***MAKE A BACKUP***
   If you proceed without making a backup and lose your data you will be mocked.
2. Create the sub-tables for each partition.
3. Make your database quiescent (either disconnect all clients or at a minimum lock the main table).
4. `INSERT` the data into each partition
   (`INSERT INTO Concept_0001 SELECT * FROM Concept WHERE …`)
5. `DROP` the original table and re-create it to inherit from the partitons.

---

Have you read [the Postgres documentation on partitioning tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html) and [table inheritence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-inherit.html)? Doing so is pretty much a prerequisite for attempting any kind of table partitioning in Postgres...

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have read these docs, but they talk only about paritioning based on the direct table attributes. And you're talking about the trigger, but I don't know how to even **create inherited table**. The problem is that I already have data in both tables :)

Comment: @dragoon Please ***read*** the documentation, don't just skim it. The documenation explains in excruciating detail how to create inherited tables - something too complex to go into here. It is not a huge inductive leap to figure out how to partition on external attributes (It's a trigger. You should be *intimately* familiar with writing triggers before attempting partitioning), nor is it hard to figure out what you need to do to partition an already existing table, but I will add details on that to my answer for you.